# Tomcat 7 starts up and then dies

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, eclipse-juno

I have Tomcat 7.0.29 running my web applications.  It starts up fine and my web apps are running, but after a set time it stops and I get following error:

> "Unable to start within 600 seconds. If the server requires more time,
>   try increasing the timeout in the server editor."

The 600 seconds is start time I have set for Timeouts.  It seems to be that even though it's working it's still trying to complete something and it will eventually time out after those 600 seconds are up.  I'm checking the log folder for Tomcat but I don't see anything in there.

It was working fine two days ago and I haven't made any modifications to the server.xml file.

Edit:  I have it started up from Eclipse (Juno)

Comment: From where do you start your tomcat? Console or Eclipse?

Comment: I have it started from Eclipse (Juno)

Comment: Can you check if you have same jdk version in workspace (Windows->Preferences->Java->Compiler) and system (check java -version from cmd)?

Comment: Thanks for your input, both versions are the same.  (1.7) I'm going to do a more thorough history check to see if someone else may have changed any of the server files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out what was causing the problem.  I had changed the settings in my network connections so that I could install plugins for eclipse and that was causing an error.  In case anyone else stumbles upon this it's in Prefrences>General>Network Connections.  I switched the Active Provider to Manual in order to activate the HTTP and HTTPS schema and that was causing the error.  Switching the Active Provider back to Direct made it go away.  I'm not really sure what the differences are though; I just know that the checkbox next to the HTTP or HTTPS schema does not get checked unless the active provider is set to manual.